# The smallest Lie subalgebra contains a subset

Tags: lie-algebras

Let $\mathfrak g$ be a Lie algebra and let $S$ be a subset of $\mathfrak g$. How to show that the Lie subalgebra generated by $S$ consists of all linear combinations of the elements $[s_m, s_{m−1}, ..., s_1]$, where $m≥ 1$ and $s_i\in S$?

Where we define $[x_1]=x_1$ and $[x_n, x_{n−1}, ..., x_1] = [x_n, [x_{n−1}, ..., x_1]]$, for $ n ≥ 1$ and $x_1,...,x_n\in \mathfrak g$.

Comment: What is your definition of a Lie algebra generated by a set $S$ ?

Comment: The smallest Lie algebra contains $S$